# Chrome Javascript Console - Reference to object output with console.log(obj)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log

Is there a way to get a `javascript` reference to an object that was output to the chrome console?

For example, say I had the following javascript:

```
top.it = {hi:'there'};
console.log(top.it);
```

This would output to the chrome console as

```
Object {hi: "there"}
```

I do this alot, and sometimes would like to get a reference to the object in the console, to run methods on it, and things like that.

**Is there a way to get a reference to objects that have been output using `console.log`?**

I know there's a way to get references to recently inspected items (e.g. `$0`), but this isn't for inspected items...

Comment: I generally just set breakpoints so I can access the variables from the console debugger.

Comment: yeah i do that too - but that's when I'm thinking ahead ;-) Sometimes during development I leave in lots of `console.log(...)` statements, and would like to jump in and work with something...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on the console log output provides the option "Store as Global Variable".

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qALFiTlVWdg) is a video of it(not created by me).